# Mifosx Installation failure

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, mifos

I was trying to install MiFOS X server on a windows 7 PC.
I installed Java runtime 1.8 -> set JRE_HOME variable.
Downloaded tomcat 1.9 -> set CATALINA_HOME variable

I installed Wamp server for MySQL server. It came with MySQL 5.7.
added MySQL drizzle JDBC driver as mentioned in its installation notes.

When I start TOMCAT server its starts successfully, but can't access my MiFOS app (/fineract-provider - the name of the app) it gives a 404 error. So I checked the manager app of tomcat. It shows that the app is not started by default. So I tried starting the app manually, which throws an error

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/fineract-provider] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fineract-provider]]]
```

So I checked the tomcat log for app. It shows

```
this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tenantDataSourceJndi)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tenantDataSourceJndi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 146 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTenantDetailsService' defined in file [C:\Users\Kailasom\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\webapps\fineract-provider\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\fineract\infrastructure\security\service\JdbcTenantDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tenantDataSourceJndi)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tenantDataSourceJndi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 158 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tenantDataSourceJndi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 172 common frames omitted
```

It shows some kind of bean is missing. What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading to MYSQL 5.5 or 5.6. 
According to mifos installation manual:

> Prerequisite Software's     Note:- Below are mandatory prerequisite
>   software's with mentioned versions only
>
> ```
> JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT >> VERSION 1.8.0_65 & above                                
> MYSQL SERVER >> Version 5.5 or 5.6
> TOMCAT >> Version 7.0.64.0 & above
> ```

Mifos X schema migrations fails when using MYSQL 5.7, This is the cause of the failed datasource connection.

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with datasource creation.
Make sure you are setting up database properties correctly.

I think you can find how to configure it at: https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Mifos+X+Installation+on+Windows#MifosXInstallationonWindows-CreateEnvironmentVariables